# What to do for Dirichlet distribution when elements of X vector may be zero

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, dirichlet-distribution

So I want to define a Dirichlet distribution over frequency vectors which are unit vectors whose elements represent the frequency with which different characters occur in a body of text. Trouble is not all the frequency vectors are guaranteed to use every character so some of the elements of the vectors can be zero. This seems really bad when you consider that you will get things like $ 0^{a_i-1} $ in the product which would be a divide by zero error if ${a_i-1}$ is negative. Is there a convention for handling this? I was considering just saying that $x < 0 \implies 0^{x} = 1 $. That way I effectively just drop elements that would be divide by zero errors; im not sure if this is ideal however.